# Structure group and mobius bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

This question was asked in my assignment of Manifolds. I am taking an online course in manifolds.

Question: (a) T cannot be the structure group of the Mobius bundle $\to S^{1}$. Here T= Translation maps group $\subset Diff ( \mathbb{R})$. $\phi \in T$ iff there exists $ x\in \mathbb{R} : \phi(x) = x+G$. Fiber $F= \mathbb{R}$.

(b) {$+/- id_{R} $}$\subset  Diff(\mathbb{R})$ can be the structure group of Mobius Bundle.

Attempt: Definition of Mobius Bundle.

[image]

[image] (a) The definition of Structure group is following: The structure group of $P: B \to M$ is $G \subset Diff(F)$ if there exists a cover of Local trivalization $\phi_{i} : V_{i} \times F \to P^{-1} (U_i)$ such that for every $m \in U_i \cap U_j$ the map $\phi_m \in G \subset Diff(F)$.

$Diff(\mathbb{R})$ is the group of all diffeomorphisms of F ie all bijective maps $f: F \to F$ st f and $f^{-1}$ are smooth.
Let on the opposite T is a structure group of  Mobius Bundle ( say MB).

$P: MB \to M$ is $T \subset Diff(\mathbb{R})$. So, there exists a local trivalization $\phi_i: V_i \times \mathbb{R} \to P^{-1}{ (U_i)}$ such that for every $m\in U_i \cap U_j$ , $\phi_m \in T\ \subset Diff(\mathbb{R})$.

But I am not able to think on how can I find a contradiction given the things in my question. Can you please help me with this!

(b) I would like to solve again by myself when I have understood the given solution of (a).

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is the Möbius bundle a cylinder?

Comment: @TedShifrin It's given on  example 10.3 page 251 Introduction to smooth manifolds by John Lee.

Comment: I asked *you* the question. Giving references to a book we don't all own isn't helpful. My question was intended to help you think about your question. You obviously need to use the actual definition of the Möbius bundle to work with it.

Comment: @TedShifrin You are right! I will add the definition. Thanks! My apologies.

Comment: Hints: How does each type of transformation act on the plane? Does the action descend to the quotient? <> LaTeX tip: Putting `$\DeclareMathOperator{\Diff}{Diff}$` at the top of your post lets you write `\Diff` in the body, avoiding the math-mode kerning issue.

Comment: What is $\phi_m$?

Comment: @BobDobbs $\phi_m : f \to \phi(m,f)$